# Lazy loading in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

All,
is it possible to specify that the entity classes mentioned in persistence.xml be lazily loaded?

I have some 300 odd entity classes and I want to specify in the persistence xml that the enetity classes be lazily loaded or do I have to go and mention it in every entity class explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** Is it possible to specify that the entity classes mentioned in persistence.xml be lazily loaded?

**A:** No, it's not possible to specify that kind of functionality in batch in `persistence.xml`. But you might find this answer on another question useful: [Is there a way to change the JPA fetch type on a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038958/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-jpa-fetch-type-on-a-method/1061631#1061631)