# Lazy loading children, that have eager collections inside

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have a problem with the following entities: Forest, Tree, Leaf. As you can imagine a forest can have a lot of trees, and a tree has a lot of leafs.

I'd like to lazy load all the trees of a forest and to eager load all leafs of a tree. My code with hibernate annotations looks like the following:

**Forest.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Forests")
public class Forest implements Comparable<Forest> {

      @Id
      @Column(name = "forestnumber", length=10, nullable=false)
      private String number;

      @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="forest")
      private Set<Tree> trees = null;

      // some other attributes and methods
```

**Tree.java**

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Trees")
 public class Tree implements Comparable<Tree> {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="tree_id", nullable=false)
        private int id;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "forestnumber", nullable = false)
        @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
        private Forest forest;

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="tree")
        @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
        private Set<Leaf> leafs = null;

        // some other attributes and methods
```

**Leaf.java**

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Leafs")
 public class Leaf implements Comparable<Leaf> {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="leaf_id", nullable=false)
        private int id;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "tree_id", nullable = false)
        @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
        private Tree tree;

        // some other attributes and methods
```

My problem: Loading a forest and calling the getTrees() Method results in a set of select Statements. Hibernate executes one statement to get all the trees and a second one for each tree to collect all the leafs.
In my opinion hibernate should generate only one statement, using a join, to collect trees and leafs at the same time.

Can someone tell me, the reason for my problem and how I can fix it?
**Thanks a lot!**

Bye the way: If I change the fetching strategy of the forest-trees to EAGER everything works fine, with only one statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to initialize

```
Hibernate.initialize(forestInstance);
```

Or write a query with join providing `fetch` to retrieve all the children eagerly.

See also

[Is there a way to change the JPA fetch type on a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038958/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-jpa-fetch-type-on-a-method)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fetch=FetchType.EAGER. Eager fetching triggers cascading select statements.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The leafs should fetched eager. But instead of select statements for each tree, I'd like to have only one select with a join. As you can see I have used the @Fetch Annotation to tell hibernate to use JOINs. But this works only, if I load the forest trees eager too. Why?

Comment: Try to remove fetch=FetchType.EAGER from  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="tree") under leaf collection to fix your issue

Comment: Removing fetch=FetchType.EAGER  from @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="tree") did not help