# What is the difference between FETCH and LOAD for Entity graph of JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, entitygraph

I'm new to JPA and I'm trying to use entity graph.
And I realized when I retrieve data, I need to specify which EntityGraphType I want to use.

I read JPA2.1 specification but I'm still not sure how can I use these 2 options properly...

the question is...

- which option should I use if I don't have any specific reqirement?
- what is the specific situation when I need to use Fetch and Load?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I will begin by answering the second part of your question.

> what is the specific situation when I need to use Fetch and Load?

There are two primary ways to load an entity in JPA, *eager* loading and *lazy* loading.  In eager loading, an entity is immediately loaded at the time its parent gets loaded.  In lazy loading, an entity is only loaded when an actual getter for that entity is called.  High performance applications tend to be biased towards lazy loading because it isn't very nice to make the end user wait for an entire table, or even group of tables, to load when the application starts up.  Now on to your second question.

You specify `FETCH` as your strategy by importing `javax.persistence.fetchgraph` in the file containing the entity.  In this case, all attributes specified in your entity graph will be treated as `FetchType.EAGER`, and all attributes *not* specified will be treated as `FetchType.LAZY`.  On the other hand, if you specify `LOAD` as your strategy by importing `javax.persistence.loadgraph` then all attributes specified in the entity graph are also `FetchType.EAGER` but attributes not specified use their specified type or default if the entity specified nothing.

> which option should I use if I don't have any specific reqirement?

That being said, it is unlikely that you do not have a specific requirement.  At the very least, you need your web application to run fast.  For this reason, you should probably default to lazy loading.  Using a `FETCH` graph is good option because it defaults to lazy loading *except* in the few special cases where you deem an attribute should be eagerly loaded.

Comment: Thank you for answering question! I could understand how I should use these options properly. I thought that if I use fetch option, I can not retrieve sub class data, but I still can do it if I call getter method but data will be retrieved from database when I call getter, not load parent class.

Comment: That link is broken. Do you have it saved so you can paste the contents here. ++1 for nice answer

Comment: But what is real difference? if I use entity graph it loads as in case of eager...