# Spring Data JPA: Switch between EAGER and LAZY when reading an object

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

My model looks like this:

```
Customer (Name, Age, ..)

   Project

      Rent

         Fault

(and maybe deeper)
```

So each Customer has a list of projects. Projects have a list of rents. And rents have a list of faults. Links are bidirectional.

Now I have a Spring MVC application which offers JSP pages and a rest interface.

There should be a service which contains two methods:

```
Customer readCustomerShallow(long customerId)
```

This one is for the website and should return a customer with name, age but no projects.

```
Customer readCustomerDeep(long customerId)
```

This one is for the rest service and should return a customer including all projects and the projects should contain all rents and the rents should contain all faults.

I want to stick using lazy loading. So readCustomerShallow() is fine already.
For readCustomerDeep() I create a deep copy of the customer object with dozer and return that.

Which solution is better?

I know I can use Hibernate.initilize() and walk through all nested objects. But this is much coding affort.
Also I know I could make relationships in the model EAGER but then readCustomerShallow() would read all data too.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:
This one does not work:

```
@Query("select c from Company as c " +
        "join fetch c.departments as d " +
        "join fetch d.persons p " +
        "where c.id = ?1")
Company findOneDeep(long companyId);
```

org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038958/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-jpa-fetch-type-on-a-method

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34546854/66686

Comment: Yes but these example have only one sublevel. Here I have 
Customer
-- Project
--- Rent
---- Fault
and I do not know how to do I JOIN FETCH then.